# jQuery, if any "one" value changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a piece of code where this guy wrote thirty functions for when a group of form values change.

I want to comprise them into a single function

```
$('#jobs_held').change(function() {
// do something, with a little variation
});

$('#residence_years').change(function() {
// do something, with a little variation
});

$('#how_long').change(function() {
// do something, with a little variation
});
```

Is there anyway I could do something like...

```
$('#jobs_held', '#residence_years', '#how_long').change(function(){
// do something, with a little variation
});
```

Comment: No way...

I mean I 'didn't' try it, but...

<_<, yeah let me try that.

Comment: Sorry, I mis-read it at first. It won't work the way you have it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Join them into a single string to use the [`multiple-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

```
$('#jobs_held,#residence_years,#how_long').change(function(){
    // do something, with a little variation

    // "this" can be used to refer to the specific element 
    //     that received the event.

    alert( this.id ); // to alert the ID of the element
});
```

...or find some common identity like a class to select them all.

Answer (score 3):

Give them all a class, e.g. "question", then simply `$('.question').change(function() {});`

You can access the id of the changed element within the function, if you need to vary it based on type.

edit: I suggested the class method over the multi-select as it's easier to maintain (you can add elements to the HTML without coming back to edit the JS).  But yeah it's true, a multi-select is more inline with the actual question.  And also, the better solution if altering the HTML is not viable.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#jobs_held,#residence_years,#how_long').change(function(){
// do something, with a little variation
});
```